# Response not coming from server using NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I have integrated my app with services using `NSURLSession` and my problem is when I send a request to the server using `NSURLConnection` it works, but when I send a request to the server using `NSURLSession`, I get a `null` response. Please advise?

### My dictionary:

```
 NSDictionary *mainDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"" ,@"DocumentNo",
                              dateString ,@"TransDate",
                              CustomerTextField.text ,@"Narration",
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],@"BranchId",
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:true]  ,@"NewTransaction",
                              addItemsArr ,@"Items",
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:0] ,@"PartyAcId",
                              @"" ,@"PartyAcCode",
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:[mainStringvalue intValue]] ,@"SalesPersonId",
                              nil];
```

### NSURLConnection:

```
NSString *jsonString = [mainDict JSONRepresentation];

NSError *theError = nil;

NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *serviceUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"my url"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serviceUrl];
[request setValue:jsonString forHTTPHeaderField:@"json"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];

// [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
//  [self performSelector:@selector(activityIndicater) withObject:self afterDelay:3];

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];

NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"jsonRequest is %@", string);

NSDictionary *jsonDictionaryResponse = [string JSONValue];
NSLog(@"jsonRequest is %@", jsonDictionaryResponse);
```

### NSURLSession:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mu url"]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:15.0];

                                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy

                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];


//[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

//[request setHTTPBody:[self encodeDictionary:params]];

//You now can initiate the request with NSURLSession or NSURLConnection, however you prefer. For example, with NSURLSession, you might do:

NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"dataTaskWithRequest error: %@", error);
    } else if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
        NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];

        if (statusCode != 200) {
            NSError *parseError;
            id responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
            NSLog(@"responseobject is %@",responseObject);

        } else {
            NSError *parseError;
            id responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];

            NSLog(@"else condtion");
            if (!responseObject) {
                NSLog(@"JSON parse error: %@", parseError);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"responseobject is %@",responseObject);
                //[self MainService:responseObject];
            }

            //if response was text/html, you might convert it to a string like so:  
            NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"final responseString = %@", responseString);
        }
    }
}];
[task resume];
```

Comment: did u try this using POSTMAN plugin to see if your url works fine or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue and when i change the `HTTPHeaderField` value in my code then i get the response..

Here is my sample code:

```
NSString *strReqParameters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_email=your_email_id&method=your_methodname"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your_URL"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];

[request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSData *postData = [strReqParameters dataUsingEncoding:4];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    //response handler code here
}];

[task resume];
```

Comment: Did you try to set request parameters like above? I am using a string for request parameters..

Comment: server here expecting NSDictionary data then how can i send as like u said  above

Comment: response is coming when i use NSurlSession but when i use NSurlSession this null resposnse coming from server

Comment: I am not aware about your server side code.. you can check it or may be you need to add some more code in server end for handling this type of request..